# Meaning of 'more than average' in the context of pretty/rather/quite/fairly

Tags: intensifiers

I have found that adverbs such as 'pretty', 'fairly', 
'quite', and 'rather' imply the same meaning as 'more than average' or 'to some extent' when these adverbs are used with gradable adjectives. But I'm very confused because I'm not understanding What 'more than average' means.

Please clarify its meanings with examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **the worst** (-100%) at one end of the scale and **the best** (100%) at the other end of the scale, **average** (0%) is half way between them. More/better than average means somewhere been **average** and **the best**

> The band was good +60%
>
> The band was pretty good + 50%
>
> The band was rather good + 30%
>
> The band was fairly good + 20%
>
> The band was not bad +10%

For stronger terms, you can use:

> The band was very good +70%
>
> The band was really good +80%
>
> The band was extremely good 90%

Note that adverb strengths are only approximate: these are my opinions and other people may see things differently.

Comment: I haven't got you yet.
 what happens if i say, The film was pretty/ quite/rather/fairly good. . . .what is the meaning of more than average ?

Comment: More than average means somewhere been average and good. "The film was pretty good" means that it was better than average.

Comment: I can't understand the phrase 'somewhere been average and good''  that you have said

Comment: I have rephrased my answer to "somewhere between average and the best". is that clearer?

Comment: i think it means not very good and just good. Am i right ?

Comment: @yubraj - I think you've said it pretty well. When it comes to films, the difference between a "good film" and a "pretty good film" is minimal, but the difference between a "good film" and a "really good film" is quite substantial. (As a footnote, I pretty much agree with this answer, too, although as the answer says, these are mere approximations. We don't generally quantify these feelings, we just try to express them approximately.)

Comment: Also, perhaps most importantly, your facial expression, gestures, tone of voice, etc. will easily push any item in this list to a different position. And don't forget that litotes can make "not bad" the highest of all. ;)